# Get the name of an image file from the root folder. The name of the folder is upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the name of a particular image file that has already been uploaded, not the one being uploaded in the folder to delete the file.

I have looked up all over google. Please help me. It is the last increment i have to make before the end of the day.

I do have the imageurl as `http://localhost/public_html/upload/123.jpeg` I have found this as my answer to delete the file but i do not know how to extract the file name

```
unlink($imagePath . $file_name);
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you want to delete the file from upload folder in project..

Comment: yes please. I am trying to delete the particular file. I have the file name and extension and now i want to delete the file

Comment: I have alread give an answer  .. If you are working in codeigniter then try with my answer.. place your filename as $image_name in code.. try it.. you will get your solution .

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a file name from a path using `basename` like this:

```
 basename($imagePath); // output: 123.jpeg
```

or without the extension:

```
basename($imagePath, ".jpeg"); // output: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = "index.php"; //type file path with extension
$title = basename($path,".php"); // get only title without extension /remove (,".php") if u want display extension
echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try it with two way..

> First : base_path

```
unlink(base_url("uploads/".$image_name));
```

> getcwd : Some times absolute path not working.

```
unlink(getcwd()."/uploads/".$image_name);
```

Comment: Its ok .. Try it.. Let me know if any issue.. @SanamShrestha